# Delete key event in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I created UITextField. I need only 4 numeric characters only allowed that textfield.

I used the following code and get result.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
   {

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber* candidateNumber;

NSString* candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

range = NSMakeRange(0, [candidateString length]);

[numberFormatter getObjectValue:&candidateNumber forString:candidateString range:&range error:nil];
NSUInteger newLength = [passwordfield.text length]; 
if(newLength>=4)
{
    [passwordfield setText:[passwordfield.text substringToIndex:3]];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"Alert"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Four Characters only allowed.."];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
    [alert show];
}
   if (([candidateString length] > 0) && (candidateNumber == nil || range.length < [candidateString length])) 
  {
         return NO;
  }
       else 
       {
      return YES;
     }

}
```

But my problem is when I press delete key, last two characters are deleting 
and same time alertview also display.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complex than it needs to be. When a user taps the backspace key, the incoming `string` is a blank string; `[NSString string]`. Here's a working solution:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {   
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    if (![numberFormatter numberFromString:string] && ![string isEqualToString:[NSString string]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (textField.text.length + string.length > 4) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                        message:@"Four Characters only allowed..." 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dylan Copeland Thanks for your code. It works very well. My problem solved. Thanks.